# Installing m4 on OpenBSD

Tags: software-installation, openbsd, source-code, xz

I know I have a lot more to learn, but I'm stuck at with something; how would I go about install `m4` (https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/M4#tab=Overview) in OpenBSD? The thing is, from everything I've read, OpenBSD does not support decompressing `tar.xz` files - I can use any help.

Comment: Decompress it somewhere else, you pc for example, and copy the uncompressed directory to OpenBSD. Altough it's doable on OpenBSD also, check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218230/why-i-cant-unpack-tar-bz2-or-tar-xz-files

Answer (score 4):

The macro processor `m4` is part of the OpenBSD base system, so you should already have it available (as `/usr/bin/m4`).

If you, for whatever reason, need GNU `m4` (as opposed to BSD `m4`), then install this from packages.  You do this as root with the command

```
pkg_add m4
```

This would install GNU `m4` and the executable would be called `gm4` (to distinguish it from the default `m4` in the base system).  The version of GNU `m4` that is packaged for OpenBSD is version 1.14.18.  This happens to be the most recent release of GNU `m4` at the time of writing.

See also:

- "[Installing Packages](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#PkgInstall)" in [the OpenBSD FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/index.html).

---

Would you want to install GNU `m4` from a `xz`-compressed source code `tar` archive, then install the `xz` compression tool using `pkg_add xz` (as root), and decompress the archive using `unxz` before unpacking the archive and building the software as usual.  I would however go with using `m4` from the base system, or possibly installing `gm4` using the pre-compiled `m4` package as described above, unless you need to test patches or make modifications to the actual source code of GNU `m4`.

Note too that the source code for GNU `m4` is also distributed as archives compressed using  `bzip2` and `gzip`. These are available in [the same FTP directory](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/) as the `xz`-compressed source code archive.

OpenBSD has a `gzip` implementation in its base system (and its `tar` is able to decompress `gzip` archives using `-x -z`), and `bzip2` is available via packages (`pkg_add bzip2` as root).